# Why do I have to reload my app for an instance of my database to show-up?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have weekgrid component that fetches data from a Firebase database

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { TaskCard } from "./TaskCard";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import db from "../database/database";
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

export function WeekGrid() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "tasks"));
      const taskList = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      setCards(taskList);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // Dummy data for the grid
  const days = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    const current_date = new Date();
    current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + i);
    const options = { weekday: "long" };
    const new_date = current_date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
    days.push(new_date.split(",")[0]);
  }

  const hours = [
    "",
    "6 am",
    "7 am",
    "8 am",
    "9 am",
    "10 am",
    "11 am",
    "12 pm",
    "1 pm",
    "2 pm",
    "3 pm",
    "4 pm",
    "5 pm",
    "6 pm",
    "7 pm",
    "8 pm",
    "9 pm",
    "10 pm",
    "11 pm",
  ];

  const numRows = 14;
  const numCols = 8;
  var fcv = 0;

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.gridContainer}>
        {Array.from({ length: numRows }, (_, rowIndex) => (
          <View key={rowIndex} style={styles.row}>
            {Array.from({ length: numCols }, (_, colIndex) => {
              fcv = colIndex === 0 ? styles.fc : styles.cell;
              return (
                <View key={colIndex} style={fcv}>
                  {rowIndex === 0 && colIndex >= 0 ? (
                    <Text>{colIndex === 0 ? "hour" : days[colIndex - 1]}</Text>
                  ) : colIndex === 0 ? (
                    <Text>{hours[rowIndex]}</Text>
                  ) : (
                    <TaskCard ri={rowIndex} ci={colIndex} cards={cards} />
                  )}
                </View>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gridContainer: {
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  cell: {
    width: 106,
    height: 100,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "red",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  fc: {
    width: 45,
    height: 100,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "red",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

And I have a component that creates a task:

```html
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import db from "../database/database";

export const CreateTaskScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [state, SetState] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    date: new Date(),
    hour: new Date(),
  });

  const [showDatePicker, setShowDatePicker] = useState(false);
  const [showHourPicker, setShowHourPicker] = useState(false);

  const SetData = (key, value) => {
    SetState({
      ...state,
      [key]: value,
    });
  };

  async function HandlePress() {
    await addDoc(collection(db, "tasks"), {
      title: state.title,
      description: state.description,
      date: state.date,
      hour: state.hour,
    });
    navigation.navigate("TaskScreen");
  }

  const handleDatePress = () => {
    setShowDatePicker(true);
  };
  const handleHourPress = () => {
    setShowHourPicker(true);
  };
  const handleHourChange = (event, selectedHour) => {
    setShowHourPicker(false);
    if (selectedHour) {
      const currentHour = new Date(selectedHour);
      hour = currentHour.getHours();
      SetData("hour", hour);
    }
  };

  const handleDateChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    setShowDatePicker(false);
    if (selectedDate) {
      const currentDate = new Date(selectedDate);
      SetData("date", currentDate);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Crear tarea</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Title"
        onChangeText={(value) => SetData("title", value)}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Description"
        multiline
        numberOfLines={4}
        onChangeText={(value) => SetData("description", value)}
      />
      <Button title="Select Date" onPress={handleDatePress} />
      {showDatePicker && (
        <DateTimePicker
          style={{ width: 200 }}
          value={state.date}
          mode="date"
          display="default"
          onChange={handleDateChange}
        />
      )}
      <Button title="Select Hour" onPress={handleHourPress} />
      {showHourPicker && (
        <DateTimePicker
          style={{ width: 200 }}
          value={state.hour}
          mode="time"
          display="default"
          is24Hour={true}
          onChange={handleHourChange}
        />
      )}
      <Button title="Save" onPress={HandlePress} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Now when I create a task the task does not show up in my week-grid component immediately instead I have to reload my app to see that my week-grid component has fetched the data why is that? how can I fix this async problem?  I have weekgrid component that fetches data from a Firebase database

Comment: chatgpt is recommending me to use useFocusEffect what do you guys think?

Comment: can the issue be related with this warning ?  : Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.%s

Comment: Swap `getDocs` (get current data once) for [`onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#onsnapshot_2) (get current data, but notify of changes) in your `useEffect` call that feeds `setCards()`. Make sure to return the unsubscribe function of `onSnapshot` from the `useEffect` callback function.